# Why are some buffers not displayed in the menu-bar?

Tags: buffers, menu-bar

Notice in the screenshot below, the `*Paradox Report*` buffer is not
displayed in the menu-bar, even though it's clearly a buffer in the
buffer-list.

[image: Diverging menus]
<sub>(source: [twimg.com](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B_cjV6HWYAAgzIW.png:large))</sub>

An easy way to test this is to run `M-: (get-buffer-create "*hello*")`, and then look for this buffer on the menu-bar.

I'm guessing the menu-bar tries to be smart and ignore some buffers
the user probably doesn't care about. My question is **what criteria
does it use?** and **how can I get around it?**

That is, when I create the `*Paradox Report*` buffer, I want to ensure
it will get displayed on the menu-bar.

---

- After I manually visit the buffer once it does get displayed on the menu-bar.
- The buffer name does not start with a space (is is `"*Paradox Report*"`).
- It seems this only happens on (development code for what might become) Emacs 25.

Comment: It sounds like a refresh / update issue with `menu-bar-update-buffers` -- perhaps its worth a bug report so they know it doesn't refresh as often as it should.

Comment: Emacs 25 does not yet exist. Presumably you mean a development snapshot *toward* what might become Emacs 25.

Comment: @Drew Yes, thanks for clarifying. I figured it was safe to refer to it as Emacs 25 because that's what you get when you build the snapshot and call `emacs-version` (and because there has been previous discussion on the fact that the next version will be numbered 25). But indeed, I meant the snapshot.

Comment: `emacs-version` numbering for development snapshots is what it is. It is the source of quite a bit of confusion, unfortunately. We should help users by clarifying, whenever possible, that a "version" such as `25.0.50.1` is **not** Emacs 25. I have removed tag `emacs-25` from posts that use it inappropriately. For now, it should apply only to discussions of what might be in the release etc., when it is released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was a bug. Fixed now in the Emacs development code for what might become Emacs 25.

The problem was that, by default, Emacs only displays the first 10 buffers on the menu-bar. But that was done slightly wrong, so it caused much less than 10 buffers to be displayed.

In the screenshot, only 4 are displayed. On a clean `emacs -Q`, I could get at most 6 buffers to display on the menu-bar.